# np.where equivalent for 1-D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to fill `nan` values in an array with values from another array. Since the arrays I am working on are 1-D [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is not working. However, following the tip in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) I tried the following:

```
import numpy as np

sample = [1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, 6, np.nan]
replace = [3, 7]

new_sample = [new_value if condition else old_value for (new_value, condition, old_value) in zip(replace, np.isnan(sample), sample)]
```

However, instead output I expected `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]` I get:

```
[Out]: [1, 2]
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you print `zip(replace, np.isnan(sample), sample)` you'll see your problem

Comment: Ok, I see my mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.where` works

```
In [561]: sample = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, 6, np.nan])
```

Use `isnan` to identify the `nan` values (don't use `==`)

```
In [562]: np.isnan(sample)
Out[562]: array([False, False,  True, False, False, False,  True])

In [564]: np.where(np.isnan(sample))
Out[564]: (array([2, 6], dtype=int32),)
```

Either one, the boolean or the where tuple can index the `nan` values:

```
In [565]: sample[Out[564]]
Out[565]: array([nan, nan])
In [566]: sample[Out[562]]
Out[566]: array([nan, nan])
```

and be used to replace:

```
In [567]: sample[Out[562]]=[1,2]
In [568]: sample
Out[568]: array([1., 2., 1., 4., 5., 6., 2.])
```

The three parameter also works - but returns a copy.

```
In [571]: np.where(np.isnan(sample),999,sample)
Out[571]: array([  1.,   2., 999.,   4.,   5.,   6., 999.])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.argwhere`. But @hpaulj shows that `numpy.where` works just as well.

```
import numpy as np

sample = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, 6, np.nan])
replace = np.array([3, 7])

sample[np.argwhere(np.isnan(sample)).ravel()] = replace

# array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.])
```

Comment: `argwhere` is just `np.transpose(np.where(...))`.

Comment: @hpaulj, thanks - yours should be the accepted answer.